# XDebug with php('--enable-debug=YES')

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I trying use XDebug (php mode './configure' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--enable-debug=YES').

In documentation of xdebug: "In case you compiled PHP yourself and used --enable-debug you would have to use zend_extension_debug".

But, in output phpinfo() module not loaded (i tried use zend_extension, too).

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension_debug=/usr/lib/php/extensions/debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

Maybe XDebug required some modules?
My loaded modules:

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mcrypt
memorylog
mongo
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
phalcon
Phar    
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
```

And one more thing:
I have 2 php version by single mac.
Before compile XDebug, i use phpize(5.5.15), but "make install" copy extension to different path (/usr/local/lib/php/extension/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so).

But phpinfo() 5.5.15 output different extension dir "/usr/lib/php/extensions/debug-non-zts-20121212".

Now i copied xdebug.so from "/usr/local/lib/php/extension/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/" to "/usr/lib/php/extension/debug-non-zts-20121212/", but is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need this answer any more, but anyway:

Xdebug doesn't need any other modules.

My guess is that before you compiled xdebug for php with --enable-debug, you called `phpize` which was from another installed php on your system. You should have run it like `full\path\to\another\phpize`, so it would set correct settings for php with --enable-debug.

The correct to include enable xdebug in php.ini is `zend_extension="/path/to/xdebug.so"`.

Hope it helps.